# UITableViewCell subclass not responding to first touch

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a couple of subviews. The design of the cell is such that I want custom highlight behavior for one of the subviews (`roundedContainer`):

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    self.roundedContainer.backgroundColor = highlighted ? [UIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:1.0] : [UIColor paperWhiteColor];
}
```

When the cell is created, I am also setting the its selection style to `UITableViewSelectionStyleNone`.

When I select the cell on my device, I am experiencing an intermittent issue where the intended action does not fire. Specifically, I am presenting a modal view controller. What's strange is that if, after selecting the cell, I touch **anywhere** else on the screen, the original modal is presented. Its as thought the animation is 'queued' somehow until another touch event is received.

Via logging, I know that `didSelectCellAtIndexPath:` and my presentation code fires immediately on the first touch.

When I remove this custom highlight implementation, normal service is resumed.

What could cause this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at more code, it's hard to tell, but it sure looks like your modal presentation is performed on a different thread than the main. You could try something along the lines of:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* present modal here */ });
```